# What will let me apply a color curve to video?

Tags: video-editor

I want to use one of these on a video:

[image: screenshot]

I can't even find *linear* adjustments in the video editor that is included with Ubuntu.

This should be trivial. What have I missed?

Comment: `ffmpeg` provides a [colour curve filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#curves-1).  Depending on your distribution version, this could be `ffmpeg` or `avconv`.

Answer (score 1):

[openmovieeditor](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openmovieeditor)
  supports color curve features. It is available in the Software Center.

References:
1) http://www.brighthub.com/computing/linux/articles/36844.aspx 
2) http://www.openmovieeditor.org/

Comment: Sadly, this appears to have become abandonware.